# Laravel: Captcha is not refeshing correctly after onclick() (mews / captcha*)

Tags: laravel, refresh, captcha

Dear friend i am trying to get this onclick() refresh captcha already for days ,but not succeed to make it display correctly a new captcha image on clickiing refresh link.

Here is my code:

This is my view page:

```
    
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="form-group refereshrecapcha">
                            {!! captcha_img('flat', ['id' => 'captcha_img']) !!}
    
                        <a href="#" onclick="refreshCaptcha()">Refresh</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
         </div>
        </div>
    ...
    
    //JS onclick refresh captcha:
     <script>
         function refreshCaptcha() {
             var captchaImg = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
             var newSrc = '/refereshcapcha'; // Add a random query string to force browser to refresh the image
             captchaImg.src = newSrc;
         }
     </script>
    ...
    @endsection
```

here is my ContactContriller:

```
        ...
        ...
            public function refereshCapcha(){
                return captcha_img('flat');
            }
        }
```

and routes:

```
Route::get('/refereshcapcha', [\App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'refereshCapcha']);
```

If i do click on that ahref in my view blade the JS is calling the route ,then route call my function in my ContactController and it is not showing the image,instead it is showing a shredded picture icon w ,instead of just refresh my captcha .

I guess i have a logic error somewhere but after days of searching still cannot figure it out ;(

p.s.
tried already github mews/captcha #52 ,#56 etc. as well on stackovflw etc. still no results.

[image: captch1]

[image: captch2]

Comment: `captcha_img();` returns an image, which you then set as `src` for the existing image? I guess your method should return `captcha_src();` instead.

Comment: nope ,not working